# Alter Woocommerce product archive structure

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to alter the Woocommerce product archive loop to make it different than the basic structure. Currently if I set the archive page to display categories and products, it will just show them all in the same grid. What I need is to display the category title above the products it contains. I will try to make my intentions visual.

**Shop grid by default:**

```
===== Shop =====       c = category, p = product
    c c p p
    p p p p
```

**What I need is to display the categories like so:**

```
===== Shop =====
 Category title
    p p p p
    p p p p
 Category title
    p p p p
    p p p p
```

In the Woocommerce template *archive-product.php* the following lines create the basic layout:

```
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

        woocommerce_product_subcategories();

          while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

          endwhile; // end of the loop.

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
```

I believe the changes need to be made there, but there don't seem to be any template files to go into the subcategories any deeper. I think I know of a way to create custom queries in there, but it seems a little messy to use that.

So my question is basically if there is a 'proper' way to achieve the result I need? Or any tips of how to approach it are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the subcategory thing get generated with this function `woocommerce_product_subcategories();`. But as you said for this layout there is no specific template file. Also, if I remember right, you cannot do this with css alone.

A little while ago I created a little plugin for a customer who also wanted a product overview structured by the product categories like you want to have.

The plugin-way is one way.

The good thing with a plugin solution is that you can show your category/products list everywhere where you can add shortcodes. (post, page, widgets)
And you can also add arguments if you just want to show a single category with products or dont want to show count or description.
I also made my list collapsable, so that a customer can collapse single categories only and can hide others.

The other way, as you already mentioned, is editing the `archiv-product.php` way.

To do this, first copy the `archiv-product.php` from the woocommerce plugin directory into your theme directory inside a new folder called `woocommerce`.
After this, you can edit the `archiv-product.php` file inside your theme directory.

With both ways you than need some logic like this:
(tried my best to comment the code as we go along)

```
// first we need to get the product category terms ....

$categories_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' // the taxonomy we want to get terms of
    //'parent' => 0, // only show terms if parent is 0 = top level terms, try it
);

$product_categories = get_terms( $categories_args ); // get all terms of the product category taxonomy

if ($product_categories) { // only start if there are some terms

    echo '<ul class="catalog">';

    // now we are looping over each term
    foreach ($product_categories as $product_category) {

        $term_id    = $product_category->term_id; // single term ID
        $term_name  = $product_category->name; // single term name
        $term_desc  = $product_category->description; // single term description
        $term_link  = get_term_link($product_category->slug, $product_category->taxonomy); // single term link


        echo '<li class="product-cat-'.$term_id.'">'; // for each term we will create one list element

        echo '<h4 class="product-cat-title"><a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term_name.'</a></h4>'; // display term name with link

        echo '<p class="product-cat-description">'.$term_desc .'</p>'; // display term description


        // ... now we will get the products which have that term assigned...


        $products_args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'product', // we want to get products
            'tax_query'     => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', // the product taxonomy
                    'field'    => 'term_id', // we want to use the term_id not slug
                    'terms'    => $term_id, // here we enter the ID of the current term *this is where the magic happens*
                ),
            ),
        );

        $products = new WP_Query( $products_args );

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) { // only start if we hace some products

            // START some normal woocommerce loop, as you already posted in your question

            woocommerce_product_loop_start(); // this will generate the start of the default products list UL

            while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); // we are using the default product template from woocommerce

            endwhile; // end of the loop.

            woocommerce_product_loop_end(); // this generates the end of the default woocommerce product list UL

            // END the normal woocommerce loop

            // Restore original post data, maybe not needed here (in a plugin it might be necessary)
            wp_reset_postdata();

        } else { // if we have no products, show the default woocommerce no-product loop

            // no posts found
            wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' );

        }//END if $products

        echo '</li>';//END here is the end of our product-cat-term_id list item

    }//END foreach $product_categories

    echo '</ul>';//END of catalog list

}//END if $product_categories
```

The thing is you cant just replace the normal woo loop (code you posted) with this code snippet above.
You will also need to delete some other lines in the `archiv-product.php` file!

I created a gist of a fully working `archiv-product.php` file [here](https://gist.github.com/LWS-Web/bc8da3cba4d0d4071fd1b695d516835e).
I think this will be helpful to you.

Also look at `get_terms()` function [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/), and WP-Query arguments [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). I just used the basic arguments that we need, surely you will need some more arguments.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I needed, thank you for the very detailed answer! Your gist is very helpful and it worked perfectly! I am now altering it to my needs, since in my structure I need it to only show the main categories at the first page.

Comment: @pascal I _think_ you should be able to achieve this if you use `'parent' => 0` in the `get_terms()` function. Will edit the answer.

Comment: @LWS-Mo Please help me, you did a great job by posting this, can you please help me. When i pasted your code on archive-product.php it worked but it pulled all categories and sub categories on the website. Can you tell me how to pull current category and sub-category?

It will help alot

Comment: @Nimesh I think you should start your own question.

Comment: @Nimesh Sorry I took to long for the comment to edit ;) I suggest you start your own question, because this is more complicated. Maybe for a start; first you need to look into conditional statements like `is_shop()` and `is_product_category()`. With this you can use `get_queried_object();` on category pages to get the current active term-object. Than you can see if this term has a parent or not (e.g. if its a subcategory or not). Maybe you need two different queries now.

Comment: @LWS-Mo I have started my own question, 
can you please help me by adding the code there as an answer?

Here is the link:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/306302/how-to-acheive-the-custom-woocommerce-category-template
thanks