# display 100 products per page on product category page

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to display 100 product on product category page at once, if there are 100 available .

Is there any specific function to do it.

Thanks,
Nimesh

Comment: There's a setting, in the Customiser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to display 100 product on product category page at once, if there are 100 available .

What should happen if you dont have 100 Products?
Or do you want to show just **all** products?

Anyway, you can try changing the query parameters (specifically here the `posts_per_page` parameter) on product category pages only.

You can use a WooCommerce hook to do this.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'my_custom_query_code' );
function my_custom_query_code( $query ){
    // only on product category pages, no other archives
    if ( is_product_category() ) {

        $limit = '100'; // the number of products

        // set the new "posts_per_page" parameter
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $limit );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm.

Can you please help me answer this question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309715/hide-some-items-from-screen-options-in-dashboard-for-products