# Hide some items from Screen options in dashboard for products

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, screen-options

I am trying to unset/hide some options in dashboard.

I am trying it for products screen.

Here is the screenshot

[image: Hide items marked in red]

Here is the code i tried to hide SKU

```
/** Hide Dashboard widget by default via Screen Options */
add_filter( 'default_hidden_meta_boxes', 'wpfa_default_screen_option' );

function wpfa_default_screen_option( $hidden ) {
/** Add WP First Aid meta box ID to default hidden Screen Options array */
$hidden[] = 'sku-hide';

return $hidden;
}
```

Though it didn't work at all.

I need to hide these three items in screenshot.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to use CSS to hide these columns and fields.

Add this in your admin.css file to hide the SKU column

```
table.wp-list-table .column-sku {
    width: 10%
}
```

To hide options in Screen Options add the following CSS in admin.css

```
.metabox-prefs label:nth-child(2), .metabox-prefs label:nth-child(11), .metabox-prefs label:nth-child(12)  {
        display: none;
}
```

FYI to double check my nth-child CSS as it may not be exact. Play around with your admin.css file while inspecting the element in the wp-admin backend.

Answer (score -1):

The best option to hide columns on the WordPress admin page is using the `hidden_columns` hook.

Example:

```php
add_filter( 'hidden_columns', 'hide_meta_box', 10, 2 );
function hide_meta_box($hidden, $screen) {
        if ( $screen->post_type == 'your_post_type' ) {
            $hidden[] ='your_column_to_hidden';
        }
        return $hidden;
}
```

This code will hide the column `your_column_to_hidden`, but the user can display it.

Comment: The question is specifically asking how to hide the options for the user to show those columns.